# How to make my footer fix to whole the application in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, footer

I have made an android app,I am having a menu(footer) at the bottom of all the activities of application,I am including them all in all the activities,It works fine,But when i go to one activity from another activity transition is made also with footer ,So My need is i want it to be fixed at the bottom,and only the activity above it should made transition.Please help me.My xml code for footer menu is as below.
**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_dest"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#D41016" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDest"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:tag="500"
                android:text="@string/dest"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="19px" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_new_book"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#D41016" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtnewBook"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/new_buk"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20px" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_social"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#D41016" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtsocial"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/Social"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20px" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_view_book"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#D41016" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtviewBooking"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/view_buk"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20px" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_contact_us"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#D41016" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtviewcontact"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/Contact_Us"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20px" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_tb2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/llfooterDest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/destination" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/llfooternewbook"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/new_booking" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/llfootersocial"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/social_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/llfooterviewBook"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/view_booking" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/llfootercontact"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/contact_us" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**menu.java**

```
  package com.eps.blancatours.uc;

    import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.eps.blancatours.R;
    import com.eps.blancatours.ui.AddBookingpopupActivity;
    import com.eps.blancatours.ui.AddDestListActivity;
    import com.eps.blancatours.ui.ContactUsActivity;
    import com.eps.blancatours.ui.DestinationsActivity;
    import com.eps.blancatours.ui.NewBookingActivity;
    import com.eps.blancatours.ui.SocialActivity;
    import com.eps.blancatours.ui.ViewBookingActivity;

    public class Menu extends RelativeLayout implements OnClickListener {

        public Context objContext;
        // ImageViews.........!
        public ImageView llfooterDestinations;
        public ImageView llfooterNewBooking = null;
        public ImageView llfootersocial = null;
        public ImageView llfooterViewBooking = null;
        public ImageView llfooterContactUs = null;

        // TextViews........!!
        public TextView destinations;
        public TextView newBooking;
        public TextView social;
        public TextView viewBooking;
        public TextView contactUs;

        // RelativeLayouts.........!!!
        public RelativeLayout rlDestinations = null;
        public RelativeLayout rlNewBooking = null;
        public RelativeLayout rlSocial = null;
        public RelativeLayout rlViewBooking = null;
        public RelativeLayout rlContactUs = null;

        public Menu(Context context) {
            super(context);
            objContext = context;
            init();
        }

        public Menu(final Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            objContext = context;
            init();
        }

        public void init() {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(objContext).inflate(R.layout.uc_menu,
                    this, true);

            llfooterDestinations = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.llfooterDest);
            llfootersocial = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.llfootersocial);
            llfooterNewBooking = (ImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.llfooternewbook);
            llfooterViewBooking = (ImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.llfooterviewBook);
            llfooterContactUs = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.llfootercontact);

            destinations = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDest);
            social = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtsocial);
            viewBooking = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtviewBooking);
            newBooking = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtnewBook);
            contactUs = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtviewcontact);

            rlDestinations = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_dest);
            rlNewBooking = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_new_book);
            rlSocial = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_social);
            rlViewBooking = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_view_book);
            rlContactUs = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_contact_us);

            rlDestinations.setOnClickListener(this);
            rlNewBooking.setOnClickListener(this);
            rlSocial.setOnClickListener(this);
            rlViewBooking.setOnClickListener(this);
            rlContactUs.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub Intent
            Intent intent = null;
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.rl_dest:
                intent = new Intent(objContext, DestinationsActivity.class);
                objContext.startActivity(intent);
                ((Activity) objContext).overridePendingTransition(
                        R.anim.animated_activity_slide_right_in,
                        R.anim.animated_activity_slide_left_out);
                ((Activity) objContext).finish();

                break;
            case R.id.rl_new_book:
                intent = new Intent(objContext, AddDestListActivity.class);
                objContext.startActivity(intent);
                ((Activity) objContext).overridePendingTransition(
                        R.anim.animated_activity_slide_right_in,
                        R.anim.animated_activity_slide_left_out);
                ((Activity) objContext).finish();

                break;
            case R.id.rl_social:
                intent = new Intent(objContext, SocialActivity.class);
                objContext.startActivity(intent);
                ((Activity) objContext).overridePendingTransition(
                        R.anim.animated_activity_slide_right_in,
                        R.anim.animated_activity_slide_left_out);
                ((Activity) objContext).finish();
                break;
            case R.id.rl_view_book:
                intent = new Intent(objContext, ViewBookingActivity.class);
                objContext.startActivity(intent);
                ((Activity) objContext).overridePendingTransition(
                        R.anim.animated_activity_slide_right_in,
                        R.anim.animated_activity_slide_left_out);
                ((Activity) objContext).finish();
                break;
            case R.id.rl_contact_us:
                intent = new Intent(objContext, ContactUsActivity.class);
                objContext.startActivity(intent);
                ((Activity) objContext).overridePendingTransition(
                        R.anim.animated_activity_slide_right_in,
                        R.anim.animated_activity_slide_left_out);
                ((Activity) objContext).finish();
                break;
            }
        }

        public void setSelectedTab(int selectTab) {
            switch (selectTab) {
            case 1:

                rlDestinations.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hover_img);
                llfooterDestinations.setImageResource(R.drawable.destination);

                break;
            case 2:

                rlNewBooking.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hover_img);
                llfooterNewBooking.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_booking_hover);

                break;
            case 3:

                rlSocial.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hover_img);
                llfootersocial.setImageResource(R.drawable.social_icon_hover);
                break;

            case 4:

                rlViewBooking.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hover_img);
                llfooterViewBooking.setImageResource(R.drawable.view_booking_hover);
                break;

            case 5:

                rlContactUs.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hover_img);
                llfooterContactUs.setImageResource(R.drawable.contact_us_hover);
                break;

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think your have to use Fragment instead of  multile Activity.

Comment: but i have completed developing,SO is there so many changes ?

Comment: Either remove the transitions between Activities, or use Fragments for the Top half and just replace those keeping your menu

Comment: @Blundell-removing transitions?what it means? i should remove the overidepending transition code?

Comment: Its working very fine with my android 4.3 device.as i needed,But when i run in lower versions this problem occurs